# Change Active Directory Password Via Spring LDAP

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I have a Java application and I want that each user have the possibility to change own password via application.

This is my code:

```
public void changePassword()
{
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("LDAPS://X.Y.Z.T/");
    contextSource.setBase("DC=example,DC=com");
    contextSource.setUserDn("username@example.com");
    contextSource.setPassword("oldpass");
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);

    byte[] li_byOldpass = encodePassword("oldpass");
    byte[] li_byNewpass = encodePassword("newpass");

    Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", li_byOldpass);
    Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", li_byNewpass);
    ModificationItem olditem = new   ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, oldattr);
    ModificationItem newitem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, newattr);
    ModificationItem repitem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, newattr);

    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
    mods[0] = olditem;
    mods[1] = newitem;

    try
    {
        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("CN=Name Surname,OU=Office,DC=example,DC=com", new ModificationItem[] { repitem });   
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Error in changing password on Active Directory: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and this is the errore that i get:

---

**[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'DC=example,DC=com'];**

---

Any help will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Hope it helps :http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/22371-ldap-error-code-32-no-such-object

Comment: Could you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the posterity

Check this link : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-ldap

Exemple of code :

```
    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    private static final String BASE_DN = "OU=Metaverse";

    protected void buildDn(UserAd user) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(BASE_DN)
            .add("OU", "Orga_Unit")
            .add("OU", "Orga_Unit")
            .add("CN", "ldap_cn").build();

        DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues(
           "objectclass", 
           new String[] 
           { "top", 
             "person", 
             "organizationalPerson"});
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", "CREATETEST");
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword","password");

        ldapTemplate.bind(context);
    }
```

Comment: It does not work, you will get error 67 attribute already exists. Baeldung floped at this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Your base is already defined in Spring LdapContextSource.
So just execute:

```
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("CN=Name Surname,OU=Office", new ModificationItem[] { repitem });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes between your new password, and then convert it to UTF-16, like this:

```
String newPass = "\"" + password + "\"";
byte[] newPassUtf16 = newPass.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```